# Python system crashing when calling another script

Tags: python

I'm doing a Python system with two buttons, and when I call one of the functions the main window hangs, how can I fix it? Although I can run the other script normally the main window crashes and I need to close it. 
Main Window code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import sys
import os
class Ui(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
def __init__(self):
    super(Ui, self).__init__()
    uic.loadUi('tela_principal.ui', self)
    self.button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'btnMonitoramento')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.monitoramento)
    self.button = self.findChild(QtWidgets.QPushButton, 'btnCadastro')
    self.button.clicked.connect(self.cadastro)
    self.show()

def monitoramento(self):
    os.system('python tela_monitoramento.py')

def cadastro(self):
    os.system('python tela_cadastrofotos.py')


app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Ui()
app.exec_()
```

The other script, I call scripts using these buttons, as you can see after calling it the main window hangs and I am forced to close the whole system:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, QMessageBox
import cv2


class App(QWidget):
def __init__(self):

    super().__init__()
    self.title = 'Tela cadastro usuários'

    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
    # self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

    #self.getNome()
    self.getInteger()
    QMessageBox.about(self, "Confirmação", "Usuário cadastrado")

    # self.show()

def getNome(self):
    # from tela_monitoramento import known_face_names, face_names, known_face_encodings

    lista = []
    text, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Nome do funcionário", "Insira o nome", 
  QLineEdit.Normal, "")
    if okPressed and text != '':
        lista.append(text)
        print(lista)

def getInteger(self):
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog
    import cv2
    import os
    i, okPressed = QInputDialog.getInt(self, "Cadastro ID do usuário", "Insira o id:", 28, 0, 100, 1)
    if okPressed:
        print(i)

    # from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QInputDialog

    cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    cam.set(3, 640)
    cam.set(4, 480)

    face_detector = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

    # id na pessoa

    # face_id = input('\n Insira o id: <return> ==>  ')

    # print("\n [INFO] Iniciando a captura da face. Olhe para a câmera.")

    count = 0

    while (True):

        ret, img = cam.read()

        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        faces = face_detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

        for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
            count += 1

            # Salvando a imagem em /usuarios
            cv2.imwrite("usuarios/funcionario." + str(i) + ".jpg", gray[y:y + h, x:x + w])

            cv2.imshow('Cadastro para reconhecimento', img)

        k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff  # ESC para sair do vídeo
        if k == 27:
            break
        elif count >= 1:  # Tira 1 foto e depois fecha
            break

    # Fechando a câmera depois de tudo
   # print("\n [INFO] Fechando")
    cam.release()
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()



    if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   ex = App()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It doesn't look like you've included the results of any debugging steps. Have you tried stepping through your code, making sure your it's running as you think it is? If you have, please edit your question to include any *specific* behavioral issues with your code. If you haven't, go and debug your program first then provide those details.

Comment: Debuging the code i get this error:                                                                                                                             
`[ WARN:0] global C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (674) SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback`